# Numpy: How to properly perform dot products over tensors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, gaussian, tensor

Let's say I wan't to plot a 2D Gaussian function over some domain

[image]

with A=1, where sigma is a 2x2 matrix and x, mu 2 dimensional vectors:

```
base = np.linspace(-1, 1, size)
x = np.array(np.meshgrid(base, base))
mu = np.array([x_0, x_1])
sigma = np.array([[a, b],
                  [b, c]])
```

I have an `x` whose shape is `(2, size, size)` and I want a resulting matrix `r` of shape `(size, size)` where each entry `r[i,j]` corresponds to `f(x[:,i,j])`.

My first attempt was to `np.vectorize` the function but it's not trivial without handling separately the meshgrid's matrices and I've read vectorizing functions is not the best solution performance-wise. Then I found `np.tensordot`, but doing

```
cent = x.T - mu
np.tensordot(cent, np.tensordot(sigma, cent, axes=[0, 2]), axes=[2, 0]).shape
```

yields a `(size, size, size, size)` shape, so there's something I'm not getting right.

How can a vectorial computation like this be applied over a tensor structure?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is no good here; it passes scalar values to your function.  You want to pass 1 or 2d arrays.  Here you are doing `dot` products, with the `ij` dimension 'going-along-for-the-ride'.  `tensordot` doesn't do that right.  `matmul` (`@`) will work, but `einsum` is easier to call correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.einsum` is one option:

```
np.einsum('jki,il,jkl->jk', cent, sigma, cent)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little what is `einsum` doing? I couldn't get much by reading the docs.

Comment: Ir essentially means <math> result_jk = sum_il cent_jki sigma_il cent_jkl </math>. It is similar to [Einstein's convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) in that indices that occur in multiple arguments but not in the result are summed over.

Comment: The way I read that is the `jk` dimensions correspond to your `[i,j]`, the outer dimensions that you were trying to 'vectorize'.  The `i` is the first `dot` (summed products) dimension (last on 1st, 2nd to the last of 2nd), `l` is the second 'dot' dimension.